# Python random string selection

Tags: python, tweepy

I am trying to select a random word that starts with a hashtag, Here is my current code and I have tried `random.choice()`, but it will only select one letter. I am guessing its because I am storing the results as one big string, maybe it needs a dictionary but I am still a little unsure how to do it.

```
trends1 = api.trends_place(1) # from the end of your code
# trends1 is a list with only one element in it, which is a
# dict which we'll put in data.
data = trends1[0]
# grab the trends
trends = data['trends']
# grab the name from each trend
names = [trend['name'] for trend in trends]
# put all the names together with a ' ' separating them
trendsName = ' '.join(names)
```

This returns

```
#NaFaltaDoQueFazerEu #Aliyaİzzetbegoviç #LawinPH  + more
```

I want to randomly select a hashtag, but at the minute its choosing a random letter from the string, i.e. doing

```
 random.choice(trendsName)
```

returns a random letter instead of a random hashtag

Comment: You are not showing us how you are picking things at random, so we can only guess here. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would just need to call `random.choice()` on `names` instead of `trendsName`:

```
import random
random.choice(names)
```

[`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) returns an element of a sequence. If your sequence is a string, then that element will be a single character from that string. However, if your sequence is a `list`, then that element will be a member of the list, which in the case of `names`, looks like it will be a hashtag.

Comment: I have tried this but what I can gather is it sometimes returns unicode because of the foreign languages returend , i.e u'#\u0627\u0644\u0645\u0639\u0644\u0645_\u0633\u0628\u0628_\u0627\u062e\u0641\

Comment: @NathanK that is a separate issue. What do you want your program to do when it returns hashtags in a foreign language?

Comment: Preferably ignore it if that's possible :D

Comment: @NathanK It is certainly possible, but there are a number of ways to handle this depending on your intended result. You should search this site for a solution that works for you since this is beyond the scope of the question in this post, or post a new question if you cannot figure it out on your own.